# SKSpriteNode was added once, but it appeared a baffling, six times

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, sprite, skspritenode

I only added the SKSpriteNode, bullet, once in my action block, but somehow it caused six different nodes to appear in my simulator. I am extremely puzzled as to how six nodes appeared in my simulator. Why did that happen? Could it possibly be a bug in Xcode? I deleted the irrelevant part of my code, so you will not have to read through all of it. Thank you in advance!

```
class MyScene: SKScene {
    var score = 0
    var playerHealth = 100
    var spaceShipHealth = 1000
    var shooterAnimation = [SKTexture]()
    var numberOfEnemies = 5


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //After load, send all of the images in the atlas to the SkTexture
        let shooter = self.childNodeWithName("shooter1")
        shooter?.zPosition = 1

        let shooterAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "shooter")
        for image in 1...shooterAtlas.textureNames.count {
            let imgName = String(format: "shooter%01d", image)
            shooterAnimation += [shooterAtlas.textureNamed(imgName)]
            let skActionBlock = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock({
                    let bullet = self.createSpaceshipBulletNode()
                    self.addChild(bullet)
                    bullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-100, 0))
                }),SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0)])
            self.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(skActionBlock, count: numberOfEnemies))
        }
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0.2)

        let bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spaceBackground.jpeg")
        let frameSize = self.frame.size
        bgImage.size = frameSize
        bgImage.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        bgImage.zPosition = 0
        self.addChild(bgImage)
    }

    func createSpaceshipBulletNode() -> SKSpriteNode{
        let spaceShip = self.childNodeWithName("Spaceship")
        let bulletX:CGFloat! = (spaceShip?.position.x)! - 200
        let bulletY:CGFloat! = spaceShip?.position.y
        let sBullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")
        sBullet.position = CGPointMake(bulletX, bulletY)
        sBullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(50, 50))
        return sBullet
    }
}
```

Comment: you are adding bullet inside a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action block that runs your `createSpaceshipBulletNode` is repeated for `numberOfEnemies` times, and that call is within a for loop that runs from 1 to `shooterAtlas.textureNames.count`. Either your for loop is running multiple times or you have 6 enemies. Perhaps you meant to add the bullets outside the loop, and only set up textures in the loop.

```
for image in 1...shooterAtlas.textureNames.count {
        let imgName = String(format: "shooter%01d", image)
        shooterAnimation += [shooterAtlas.textureNamed(imgName)]
}
let skActionBlock = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock({
    let bullet = self.createSpaceshipBulletNode()
    self.addChild(bullet)
    bullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(-100, 0))
}),SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0)])

self.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(skActionBlock, count: numberOfEnemies))
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0.2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How did I not see it before!? I meant to only set up my textures in my for loop.